# GSM Modem AT commands memory "OM" "DM"

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem

I am currently working on a project that involves automating sending and receiving text messages using a RAZR v3.

Usually, when choosing the memory for the phone, there is "ME", "SM",or "MT" which stands for phone, sim, and both respectively. However when inserting a specific sim card, its different. When I do a AT+CPMS=?, I get
("MT","IM","OM","BM","DM"), ("OM","DM"),("IM")

I know what MT is, and BM is for broadcast messages. What does "OM" and "DM" stand for and what are their relations to the other memory types?

I used this site for basic memory knowledge: 
http://www.developershome.com/sms/cpmsCommand.asp

and according to this site for motorola commands, it seems as if "OM" and "DM" are unknown as well(Do a ctrl+f with the keyword "CPMS"): http://gatling.ikk.sztaki.hu/~kissg/gsm/at+c.html#27.07me

I have already tried searching the internet but to no avail. If there is an article that illustrates in depth on what I am asking, I would appreciate it if you would please point me to that location, otherwise please help with the question!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to reddit user 1991_vg, "OM" and "DM" stand for Outgoing Messages and Draft Messages respectively. On a RAZR phone, they represent folders where messages are stored, and thus should be able to send messages from those folders. Here is the motorola at commands for anybody who has this problem: http://read.pudn.com/downloads139/doc/599044/AT_Commands_Ref.pdf

In addition, here is a nice document posted by reddit user "farnz" for the specifications of modems: http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27005.htm