# Bypass message storage when sending SMS with AT commands

Tags: sms, at-command, modem, cellular-network

I have an array of Motorola Razar v3m's containg about 26 phones now. I have a multi-threaded software platform I built which manages each phone and message routing/timed-wait tasks and all of that.

When I issue:

> AT+CMGW="1234567890"message<26><27>

It takes nearly 30 seconds to write the message to the phone memory, I then get send the message using:

> AT+CMSS=`messageIndex`

and that takes another 30 seconds.

I have tried using AT+CMGS but can't get that functionality to send a message successfully at all.

I need this to be reliable, but with this method/phone combination, I wouldn't even depend on it to tell me Happy Birthday once a year.

Is there another way to send an SMS without storing it to memory first? Not only is it slow; **but eventually causes the phone to no longer send messages at all**, even if they are deleted after by AT+CMGD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the you are writing to the sim memory since it is so slow.
From the description of `AT+CMGW` in [27.005](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm):

> Execution command stores message (either SMS-DELIVER or SMS-SUBMIT) to memory storage `<mem2>`.

and earlier in "3.1 Parameter definitions":

> `<mem1>` string type; memory from which messages are read and deleted (commands List Messages +CMGL, Read Message +CMGR and Delete Message +CMGD); defined values (others are manufacturer specific):

```
"BM" broadcast message storage
"ME" ME message storage
"MT" any of the storages associated with ME
"SM" (U)SIM message storage
"TA" TA message storage
"SR" status report storage
```

> `<mem2>` string type; memory to which writing and sending operations are made (commands Send Message from Storage +CMSS and Write Message to Memory +CMGW) ); refer  for defined values

The value of `<mem1>` and `<mem2>` is configured with `AT+CPMS`, preferred message storage (notice you should [set both to the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746283/23118)). So my guess is that if you run `AT+CPMS?` it will return `+CPMS: "SM", ..., ..., "SM", ...`. If my guess is correct you should just switch to another storage on the phone ("ME", "MT" or "TA" - check with `AT+CPMG=?` what it supports (and it might support [additional storages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903073/23118) compared to the standard)) which will be much faster that the sim storage.

---

Using `AT+CMGS` should be possible, but notice that you do need to [wait for `"\r\n> "`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) before sending the payload. When you say you did not get that one to work I assume you had some trouble with regards to proper parsing of the responses and proper waiting.

Comment: I'll award you --- because you ARE correect, but in short, the answer was abandoning the Motorola Razr v3m phones -- they are too unreliable. They eventually just quit sending messages, and i have 70 phones I have tried. I eventually just built an Arduino with a GSM shield and coded it how I needed -- it sends texts in under a second.